# Large data set contour plot in R/Splus?

Tags: r, plot, contour, s-plus, large-data

I am working with very large data sets named `u10` and `u10s` consisting of 30016950 values.

Now what I am trying to do is a contour plot to aid in the comparison of the two (a scatter plot is just too messy).

I've looked around and found code such as;

```
x<-u10
y<-u10s
zfunc <- function (x,y) {
1/2/pi*exp(-(x^2+y^2)/2)
}
z<-outer(x,y,zfunc)

contour(x,y,z,nlevels=10)
```

However,

```
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 6835453.9 Gb, 
Reached total allocation of 4025Mb: see help(memory.size)
```

This works with a small data set but unfortunately not a large one like mine.

I have also tried using `kde2d` which again works with a small data set but not mine since it produces the same error.

Any hints on how I would go about producing such a contour/filled.contour plot successfully in R/splus?

Comment: maybe use a high-resolution `hexbin` plot and then base the contours on the hexbinned data?

Comment: perhaps using summary statistics could help? When dealing with such a dataset, one option is to aggregate (converting your numeric variables into factors). Another option is to subset your data, and plot a few subsets to see if the sample is representative. A 10% of your data should do. [Check out the ggplot documentation for this](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/)

Comment: Do you understand why `outer` wanted to use 6.8Pb - yes Petabytes - of memory? It was trying to create a vector for each x for each y - about 9x10^14 values.

Comment: @Spacedman `outer` actually needs to create two vectors of that size and pass them to `zfunc`.

Comment: @Roland I suspect it failed the first time :)

Comment: @Spacedman buy more RAM?

Comment: @BenBolker Thanks! I didn't know there was such a plot and that suits my need quite nicely.